# How to set up Realm object Server with nginx?

Tags: nginx, centos, realm-mobile-platform

I am on the CentOS platform, and I have successfully installed Realm object server. But I am using the nginx proxy services, thus I have to disable the ROS proxy. Unfortunately, I was not able to access the dashboard. I believe I am missing some configuration on the nginx side. There are 2 ports that Realm is listening on, do I need to forward BOTH of the ports in nginx? Is there any configuration instructions that someone can share? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Realm Object Server (v 1.4.1) on a Digital Ocean server with Nginx. Here's the virtual server I created:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name realm.mydomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
}
```

It wasn't clear to me from the documentation that the easiest is to leave the Realm Proxy Module enabled.

Note 1: I am using it as a subdomain of one of my applications but that was only to avoid registering a new domain name.

Note 2: It took me a while to realize that Nginx has to function as a WebSocket proxy and needed the last two configuration lines. See [docs](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) for additional details.

Comment: On a related note, while I haven't looked into it too much, putting the `proxy_pass` under a location like `/ros/` seems to cause the setup screen to break (`/login` doesn't redirect and `/setup` is broken if navigated to manually).